# How to set the Border on a Tile

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I tried to set the Border on a Tile but it just doesn't want to show.

```
   <mah:Tile Content="Tile" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="692,250,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderBrush="#FFE01C1C" BorderThickness="3"/>
```

No errors are thrown and i can't really see in the Source Code, https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/master/MahApps.Metro/Themes/Tile.xaml , why this wouldn't work. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should edit default `Tile` theme.

1) Add `ResourceDictionary` (TileTheme.xaml):

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:mah="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro">
    <Style TargetType="mah:Tile">
        <Setter Property="Width"
                Value="140" />
        <Setter Property="Height"
                Value="140" />
        <Setter Property="Margin"
                Value="3" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="Background"
                Value="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
                Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin"
                Value="0.5,0.5" />
        <Setter Property="TitleFontSize"
                Value="16"/>
        <Setter Property="CountFontSize"
                Value="28"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="mah:Tile">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                    Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <ContentPresenter RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Count}"
                                       FontSize="{Binding CountFontSize, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </StackPanel>

                        <Label Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                               VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                               Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}">
                            <AccessText Text="{Binding Title, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                        Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                        TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                        FontSize="{Binding TitleFontSize, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                        Margin="3" />
                        </Label>
                    </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Button.IsPressed"
                                 Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.98"
                                                    ScaleY="0.98"
                                                    CenterX="0.5"
                                                    CenterY="0.5" />
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

2) Import this resource dictionary to your app (by edit `App.xaml`):

```
<Application ...>
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="TileTheme.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

[Here](http://1drv.ms/1n7p5Dc) is example solution.

Comment: Ahhh, I see putting a border in front of the grid.. Cool thank you